# Why I do not see the log in the shell trying to run client script with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do a "Server sent event" with express.
I can get the data by requesting it from the browser but i need to elaborate this data. 
Running the script(client) from shell I can not see anything.

What am I doing wrong or am i forgetting?

Server side:

```
var express = require("express")
, http = require("http")
, fs = require('fs')
, ursa = require('ursa')
, url = require('url')
, querystring = require('querystring')
, jsonObject;


var app = express();

app.use(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
  });
  console.log("sending data over eventsource...");
  response.write("\n");
  response.write("data:ok");
});

http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

Client side:

```
var EventSource = require('eventsource');

var source = new EventSource("http://localhost:8080");
source.addEventListener('data', function (e) {
var log = e.data;
console.log(log);
});
```

Comment: Do you see `sending data over eventsource...` in the shell?

Comment: I tried to log source, this is the output: { reconnectInterval: 1000, close: [Function] }.. yes i see!

Comment: Try to add `console.log()` in more places to see which parts of the code get executed and which are skipped. Maybe the source is created, all events are flushed and then your listener is added.

Comment: i think the problem is into 'addEventListener()', i inserted a text log before 'var log' declaration but shell returns nothing..

Comment: You need to add the log before the function to see whether the event listener is even installed.

Comment: i logged 'source' before 'addEventListener() and i can see output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
i changed simply the type  of event in addEventListener() from 'data' to 'message', like this:

```
var EventSource = require("eventsource");

var source = new EventSource("http://localhost:8080");

source.addEventListener("message", function (e) {

var log = e.data;
console.log(log);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a `\n` after the data to signify the end of that event.

Comment: You should provide a fixed version of OP's code.  Just because the people on Stackoverflow like that.

Comment: @Xero: On the contrary.  We should force questioners to learn how to write their own code.